# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$('.entry-content').offset().top')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object `(evaluating '$('.entry-content').offset().top')`

i have next code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
console.log("Start");
(function($) {
    "use strict";
    var dh;
    var faded = false;
    dh = $('.entry-content').offset().top;
    if ($(window).width() > 1000 && $('body').hasClass('single'))
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var offset = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (offset > 270 && faded != true) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.adslot_1 center').fadeOut(400, function() {
                        $('.adslot_1 center').css({
                            'position': 'static'
                        }).fadeIn();
                    });
                }, 300)
                faded = true;
                return;
            }
        })
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka3dd.jpg)
Help solve the problem

Comment: Please explain what your code is supposed to do. What is the expected result?

Comment: Does `.entry-content` exist on every single page the script is executed? If it does not, the offset method will return an undefined object and thereby accessing the top property will throw an error. Implement a check if the div exists before doing anything else.

Comment: This class is placed only on the news page, the main page thing is not. Therefore, we get an error on the main page. How can it be eliminated?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you could more information of what it is exactly that you are trying to do.

But from what did provide, $('.class') returns an array of elements with that class. And the error probably means that there are no such objects.

Also, the correct way would be to get the element by ID or filter the element from the array you get from your current try.

Comment: This class is placed only on the news page, the main page thing is not. Therefore, we get an error on the main page. How can it be eliminated?

Comment: You could first get the array from $('.entry-content'). Then check if it's length is > 0 and then perform your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Element.getBoundingClientRect().top` since some elements does NOT define `offset.top`. E.g. SVGs

[More Info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Plus

> The amount of scrolling that has been done of the viewport area (or
>   any other scrollable element) is taken into account when computing the
>   bounding rectangle. This means that the rectangle's boundary edges
>   (top, left, bottom, and right) change their values every time the
>   scrolling position changes (because their values are relative to the
>   viewport and not absolute).

Comment: This class is placed only on the news page, the main page thing is not. Therefore, we get an error on the main page. How can it be eliminated?

Comment: can you please explain what you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: This script attaches ads when scrolling

Comment: "This class is placed only on the news page, the main page thing is not" what does thins mean? or add the whole code

Comment: The .entry-content class is only on the news page. But the script is displayed on all pages of the site